# What different between 2 json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have theses two code to make json from array in PHP:

**Code 1**

```
$array_1 = array("A","B","C");
$array_2 = array("D","E","F");
echo json_encode(array('array_0'=> array('array_1'=>$array_1,'array_2'=>$array_2)));
```

Output :

```
{
    "array_0":
    {
        "array_1": ["A", "B", "C"],
        "array_2": ["D", "E", "F"]
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
$A = array('A','B','C');
$B = array('array_1' => $A);
$C = array('D','F','E');
$D = array('array_2' => $C);
$E = array($B, $D);
$F = array('array_0' => $E);
echo json_encode($F);
```

Output :

```
{
    "array_0": [
        {
            "array_1": ["A", "B", "C"]
        },
        {
            "array_2": ["D", "F", "E"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is there a difference between the 2 output? Which one is correct?

Thanks you !

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  Both are correct.  They are 2 different structures.  Why would would be "correct" and one "incorrect"?

Comment: Why it different structures ? I think 2 code is the same ?

Comment: "Code 2" is not the same.  In "code 2", you are doing `array($B, $D)`.  You are making an array of 2 arrays.  That's different than "code 1".  What you should be doing is: `$B['array_2'] = $C; $F = array('array_0' => $B);`.  Get rid of `$D` and `$E`.  You want to add `array_1` *and* `array_2` to the *same* array not add them to their own arrays.

Comment: this would be a good situation for `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. If you use those functions instead of `json_encode()`, you will see that the structures are not exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `code_2` you create `array_0` as:

```
array(array('array_1' => $A), array('array_2' => $C));
// ^$E   ^$B                   ^$D
```

Whereas the similar step in your `code_1` is:

```
array('array_1' => $A, 'array_2' => $C)
```

You can make them similar by defining `$E` in `code_2` as following:

```
$E = array_merge($B, $D)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, array_0 is an associative array that is translated to js object.

In the second case, array_0 is a numeric array that is translated to js array.

There is no correct/wrong. They are both correct.